# CSS Navigation Menu

Tags: html, css

How can I have logo, menu items, and social media icons on the same line within the navigation? I like to have logo to the left, menu items in the middle, and social media icons to the right on the same line if that makes sense.

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div id="nav-wrapper">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="service.html">Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="social">
          <li class="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/jason.murray.3975012"</a>Facebook</li>
          <li class="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/jmurray504"</a>Twitter</li>
          <li class="linkedin"></li><a href="http://http://www.linkedin.com/pub/jason-murray/42/249/440/"</a>Linkedin</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>   


CSS

.social {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.facebook li {
        background: url(Image/facebook.png);
        height: 20px;
        width: 18px;
}

.twitter li {
        background: url(Image/twitter.png);
        height: 20px;
        width: 18px;
}

.linkedin li {
        background: url(Image/linkedin.png);
        height: 20px;
        width: 18px;
}
```

Comment: your html is not valid. Re-arrange your tags

Comment: Your html is valid except an extra </li> in your last li, but your CSS is no good.. should be maybe .twitter a (not li).. etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There you go](http://jsfiddle.net/sNLgz/). I fixed everything, made it pretty and just like you described it.
new CSS:

```
nav {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #008cff;
    font-family: arial;
}
.nav-wrapper a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
}
nav a:hover {
     background: #47ACFF;
}
.nav-wrapper {
     padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
nav ul, nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
}
.social {
    float: right;
}
```

Only problem is it doesn't fit small screens (phones, tablets etc.), so I would recommend using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

Comment: Well played sir! Well played. Now I would like to add social media icons in the menu instead of the words (facebook, twitter etc.) By adding the images, will this have an negative impact by moving other elements within this menu?

Comment: I suggest using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). It's free, easy to use and the icons are just like text so they fit perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get elements to show in line, is to add "display:inline", or in this case I'd go for "display:inline-block"

A simple solution for this example would be:

```
.nav ul, .nav li { display:inline-block; }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/dj2da/

(Also fixed your html by removing the first closing `</li>` tag in the Linkedin link)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
.nav li, .nav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Boilerplate and Bootstrap? I understand that these two are common in terms of developing a responsive website. What do you guys think on using these two products? I guess I'm more old school still working through Dreamweaver CS3. I haven't created websites since 2009 and I know things have changed since then with technology (Mobile & Tablets). With that being said, I just need a few pointers on how to incorporate it into my website as well as using programs to alleviate cross browser compatibility. I've heard modernizr is a good tool to use.